# How to make Mercurial find updated version of Python?

Tags: linux, installation, python, redhat-enterprise-linux, mercurial

My system is RedHat 5 Linux and has default *python 2.4* installed. In order to execute [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/) 1.81, I tried to upgrade python from *2.4* to *2.6* and I thought I saved it in a different directory. I have put hard link from *python 2.6* to *python*. Now, I removed it and hope to make python pointing back to *python 2.4* in order to avoid version conflicting.

Here is the command I have used to remove the hard link between *python* and *python 2.6*:

```
find -xdev -samefile /usr/bin/python | xargs rm
```

Then I used commands as:

```
ln -s /usr/bin/python2.4 /usr/bin/python
ln -s /usr/bin/python2.6 /usr/local/bin/python
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
Change first line of hg to #!/usr/bin/env python
PYTHONHOME=/usr/lib/python2.6
PYTHONPATH=/usr/lib/python2.6
```

Then when I typed `whereis python`, here are the results.

```
/usr/bin/python2.4 
/usr/bin/python 
/usr/lib/python2.4 
/usr/lib/python2.6 
/usr/local/bin/python 
/usr/include/python2.4 
/usr/include/python2.6 
/usr/share/man/man1/python.1.gz
```

Then when I typed `which python`, it pointed to `usr/bin/python`. When I typed `python -V`, it showed `python 2.4.3`. It seems to be pointing back to *2.4.3*. Then, when I used the command

```
python -c "import sys; print '\n' .join(sys.path)"
```

It showed:

```
/usr/lib64/python24.zip
/usr/lib64/python2.4
/usr/lib64/python2.4/plat-linux2
/usr/lib64/python2.4/lib-tk
/usr/lib64/python2.4/lib-dynload
/usr/lib64/python2.4/site-packages
/usr/lib64/python2.4/site-packages/Numeric
/usr/lib64/python2.4/site-packages/gtk-2.0
/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages
```

I tried to find the paths of *python 2.6* by typing `find / -name python2.6`, it showed

```
/usr/include/python2.6
/usr/lib/python2.6
/usr/lib64/python2.6
```

Here are my questions :

1. How can I change the replace the results from the on-liner above to *python 2.6* ?
2. Why cannot I find a directory such as `/usr/bin/python2.6` or `/usr/local/bin/python2.6` ? Does it mean I installed my *python 2.6* incorrectly or accidentally removed the directory ? Is anything wrong about the results I got from those commands I entered ?
3. Any idea how to make the system execute *python 2.6* when I used "hg push" ?
4. Should I install the *python 2.6* again at /usr/local/bin ?

Comment: You only need Python 2.4 to run any version of Mercurial, even Mercurial 2.1. Are you trying to use Python 2.6 to get better support for verifying SSL certificates?

Comment: When I used command such as "hg push", the system complained with an error message such as "abort: certificate checking requires Python 2.6
". I assume that means it requires Python 2.6 or I am wrong ? Thanks

Comment: Python 2.6 is required to check the SSL certificates. I'm a bit surprised it aborts, but you can try with `hg push --insecure` to let Mercurial know that you cannot verify the certificates with your Python. I think you can also configure a host fingerprint, see [the wiki page](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/CACertificates).

Comment: Hi Thank you so very much ~. I tried "hg push --insecure".It avoided the certificates error and let me push successfully. Will there be any problem if I used hg push --insecure ?

Comment: @Raystafarian Did you help edit the question posted ? Thank you very much,:)

Answer (score 0):

1. Install [virtualenv](http://virtualenv.org) and [virtualenvwrapper](http://www.doughellmann.com/docs/virtualenvwrapper) (easy_install worked for me, but don't forget to add the line `source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh` to your shell startup script and then source the startup script to use the wrapper)
2. Run `mkvirtualenv -p /usr/lib/python2.6 ENVNAME` (where `ENVNAME` is whatever you want to name it, maybe `hg`?)
3. Add `workon ENVNAME` to your shell init script (.profile, .*shrc, etc)

Now your system will still be able to use 2.4, and all of your shells will use 2.6. Be careful, because this could break calls to other system-installed applications, if their dependencies aren't in your virtual environment. But, since you now have pip, it should be easy to `pip install $WHATEVER_IS_MISSING` (or run the `deactivate` command to drop out of your virtual environment, do your thing, and `workon` back to where you were).

If you find hg instances started by processes outside of shells (e.g. file manager integration?) then I recommend placing this small script on your path and configuring those processes to invoke it instead.

```
#!/bin/bash # or whatever your shell is
workon ENVNAME
hg $*
```

(Note, you can disable the `(ENVNAME)` prompt by setting `VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT` earlier in your init script than the `workon` line)